# Java Swing how to draw polygons with coordinate params when layout is not absolute

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt

I am trying to make a little GUI using swing. I would like it to draw a polygon on a JPanel that has a GridBagLayout. How do I do this? Can I give the polygon coordinates to draw from? Are the coordinates based on the cell the polygon is drawn in, or the JPanel, or the Frame?

Initially to test, I have just tried to draw a line with coordinates in the class I have, and then add it to the JPanel. Nothing is drawn.

The overriden paintComponent method I have in the class UniverseDisplay is:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawLine(20,  20,  30,  30);
    System.out.println("PAINTED");
}
```

The function I have which sets up a UniverseDisplay and which causes paintComponent to be called is as follows:

```
public void setUpGenerateButton(){
    generateButton = new JButton("Generate Model");
    generateButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    Universe u = new Universe(reflexive, transitive, symmetric, hereditary);
                    World w = new World(u);
                    u.addWorld(w);
                    Tree t = new Tree();
                    t.setRoot(t);
                    t.setData(expressions, 0, expressions.size());
                    t.setInitialWorlds(w);
                    t.setInitialUniverses(u);
                    t.evaluateModalExpressionV2(u);
                    /*
                     * this bit below isnt actually painting anything on the 
                     * JPanel even though paintComponent() is being called properly
                     */
                    UniverseDisplay ud = new UniverseDisplay(u);
                    rightPanel.add(ud);
                    rightPanel.revalidate();
                    rightPanel.repaint();
                }
            });
}
```

The JPanel is set

```
public void setUpPanels() {
    setUpTextInputField();
    setUpGenerateButton();
    setUpPropsPanel();
    setUpButtons();
    setUpClearButton();


    leftPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    rightPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    rightPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

    /*
     * create a new constraints for each new component, to avoid bugs
     */
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    leftPanel.add(inputL, constraints);

    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    leftPanel.add(inputField, constraints);

    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(0, 15, 0, 0);
    leftPanel.add(generateButton, constraints);

    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    leftPanel.add(propsL, constraints);

    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    leftPanel.add(propsPanel, constraints);

    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    constraints.ipadx = 30;
    constraints.ipady = 70;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 15, 0, 0);
    leftPanel.add(buttonPanel, constraints);

    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    leftPanel.add(clearButton, constraints);

    add(leftPanel);
    add(rightPanel);
}
```

Why is that no line is drawn in the JPanel? How do I go about drawing shapes in a JPanel that does not have its layout set to null?

I hope that is enough information for a useful answer :)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

When you do custom painting you are responsible for determining the preferred size of the component. This is done by overriding the `getPreferredSize()` of your component.

So in your case you need to use:

```
@Overrid
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(50, 50);
}
```

Then the layout manager can use the preferred size information to position the component in your layout.